# Chart.js microsoft edge display issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js, microsoft-edge

I have created a mixed chart using chart.js library, unfortunately when testing the script on Microsoft Edge or Safari the chart does not display properly, lines are barely visible, legend is almost completely hidden unless hovered, axes also has a very poor labels.

Is there a way to fix the issue? Important to mention is that I had the same issue using d3.js. At first I thought it's SVG causing this issue but then chart.js is using canvas instead and the problem stil occurs.

https://vantrilio.github.io/charts/ - my example

---

Screens to compare

Google Chrome - everything is correct here:

[image]

Microsoft edge - legend is gone, axes labeling very thin, line chart is barely visible:

[image]

Safari - legend is gone, line chart is barely visible:

[image]

Any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Marcin!  Can you share the code that is not working?

Comment: https://github.com/vantrilio/charts
Here it is :) It is working quite well on Chrome, my main issue is displaying the chart in Microsoft Edge, it just looks completely different, lines are gone, fonts are very thin, legend is completely gone.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on how to ask a good question, as this will help the community better understand your issue and provide you with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's better to paste the relevant code into your question instead of making people search through your repository for exactly where your problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that below reasons cause this issue.

-> IE and Edge does not support globalAlpha for drawImage of SVG graphics.
-> IE 10 canvas doesn't support setLineDash or lineDashOffset.

-> In IE 11 canvas.toDataURL() does not work if the canvas has images
   with data URI sources.

Reference:

[Canvas (basic support)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas)

[Chart JS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/)

You need to contact Chart JS for support. This library is developed by them. so they may available with any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have fixed the problem, for line chart problem it was enough to switch from RGBA to HEX colors, thin font was fixed just by changing the font family and it's weight - same with the legend.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    stacked: true,
    barPercentage: 0.6,
    fontStyle: 'bold',
    ticks: {
            fontFamily: "Verdana",
            fontStyle: 400
        }
  }],
  yAxes: [{
    stacked: true,
    fontStyle: "bold",
    fontSize: 80,
    ticks: {
            fontFamily: "Verdana",
            fontStyle: 400,

        }
  }]
},
```